# Should this variable release manually?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Memory need to be release for alloc, retain and copy.  My question is for following situation where I retain the UIImage property, but it was autorelease by the function of imagedNamed. Should I still release following variable?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you edited this to fix the problem.  Now the answers below don't make sense.  This makes it hard for other people to follow and learn.  Was your original code like this? `[self image] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to release image since you retained it.

Comment: But he's accessing the ivar, not the property. So retain isn't called.

Comment: Right. its an auto release object. You need to worry about releasing only those objects that you either allocate or retain. In your example, if you say self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
 then it gets retained, as its property gets accessed. If you dont say self.image as in your example, you are not retaining it.

Comment: Still has to do a self.image = nil  and a [image release]. All retained properties have to be released in the dealloc.

Comment: @jini: It is not necessary to do both `self.image = nil` and `[image release]` in dealloc. The first will make the second irrelevant.

Comment: @BJ Homer  It will not make it relevant. Image is a pointer that points to the address in memory. If we just do [image release] then we will deallocate the memory however image will still point to that non available memory. Setting it to nil ensures that it will not receive any more messages.

Comment: Yes, but if you do `self.image = nil`, then `image` is nil. `[nil release]` does absolutely nothing. Thus, doing `self.image = nil; [image release];` is exactly the same as `self.image = nil;`

Comment: @jini Further, if you did `[image release]; self.image = nil;`, then you'd be over-releasing the object pointed to by `image`, because `self.image = nil` will call the setter, which will release it.

Comment: Even further, once dealloc has run, you don't really need to worry about the object's instance variables receiving further messages — if anybody is accessing those ivars at that point, they're *already* invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you don't use your property but assign autoreleased UIImage object to your iVar directly, so you need

1. retain your image (or better actually use property) - otherwise your image object will be destroyed when you exit current scope and accessing it in other methods will result in an error. So use:

   ```
   self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   ```
2. Release your image in dealloc method

Comment: Sorry. Mistype for self.image.